# Transportation probem

Tags: optimization, optimal-transport

The so-called transportation problem in mathematics asks about an optimal way to match demand and supply.

Assume we have $m$ suppliers and $n$ factories demanding these supplies. There exists a cost $c_{i, j}$ to transport goods from suppliers $i$ to factory $j$. Each factory has a demand of $d_i$ and each supplier has a capacity of $e_i$.

The problem turns into a linear programming problem to minimize the cost considering the amount of supply and demand.

I have an extra condition on the number of transport from a supplier. Meaning that the number of transport from a supplier with $e$ item in its stock, should be appropriate to $e$.
For example if a supplier has 50 items, then it can send items to a maximum of $2$ factories, if it has 200 items it can send goods up to $8$ factories and $\cdots$. More precisely the extra condition in the example is: the maximum number of transport allowed is the integer part of (total supply)/25.

How should I incorporate this condition into the linear programming problem?

Comment: You are going to have to make the condition more precise: for example can $49$ be sent to $2$ factories?  Can $50$ be split into $20+30$ or must it be $25$ each.  Then you introduce new constraints (e.g. each positive delivery must be at least $25$).  This will complicate finding a solution and may prevent you using standard techniques

Comment: Thanks for the comment. More precisely the condition in the example is:
Maximum number of transport allowed is the integer part of e/25. Therefore 49 can be sent to only one factory.

There are no extra conditions, so 50 can be split in any way you desire. It can be split into 
20+ 30, 15+35 or 5+45 ...